# What is the second case of ros::ok() return false?

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [topic programmoing tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)

Here says that

ros::ok() will return false if:

```
1. a SIGINT is received (Ctrl-C)
2. we have been kicked off the network by another node with the same name
3. ros::shutdown() has been called by another part of the application.
```

I understand 1 and 3,but what is the second situation?

How to kicked off the network by another node with the same name?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11301/what-is-the-second-case-of-ros::ok()-return-false?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-09-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figure out 'we have been kicked off the network by another node with the same name' by tring two sample code:

node_test.cpp:

```
 #include "ros/ros.h"
 
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
    //ROS的初始化
    ros::init(argc, argv, "basic_node");
    ROS_INFO("%s","Hello 1!");
    //讓ROS進入無窮迴圈，但能進行事件處理
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
 }
```

node_test2.cpp

```
 #include "ros/ros.h"
 
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
    //ROS的初始化
    ros::init(argc, argv, "basic_node");
    ROS_INFO("%s","Hello 2!");
    //讓ROS進入無窮迴圈，但能進行事件處理
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
 }
```

When I run the first,and second.

The first will crash on following messages:

```
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/node/basic_node$ ./bin/basicNode
 [ INFO] [1316859193.830963744]: Hello 1!
 [ WARN] [1316859279.686228002]: Shutdown request received.
 [ WARN] [1316859279.686357767]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node      registered with same name]
 
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/node/basic_node$
```

Thank you~

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2011-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-09-24**:
Right. This provides a way to restart a node if it seems to have stopped working.